# Linking problems between two packages

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone

I have a very strange problem. I am working on creating an interface to a Katana arm by Neuronics.
There have already been made one here http://www.ros.org/wiki/katana, but it is way to bloated and user defined for my purpose. So what I did was to extract the core package for the katana arm. This is actually just a ROS wrapper to the original interface API created by Neuronics. What the wrapper does is compiling the API and setup export paths in the manifest file:

```
  <export>
    <cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/KNI_4.3.0/include" lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/KNI_4.3.0/lib/linux -L${prefix}/KNI_4.3.0/lib/linux
     -lKNIBase -lKinematics -lKNI_InvKin -lKNI_LM"/>
  </export>
```

Afterwards I created my own package which included the katana API wrapper package in its manifest file. This gave me seamlessly access to the API's include file and everything compiled nicely until today. Not matter what I try will the linking of my interface e.g. return the following error:

```
/home/aslund/Dropbox/MasterProject/kni/KNI_4.3.0/include/KNI_LM/lmBase.h:73: undefined reference to `CikBase::~CikBase()'
/home/aslund/Dropbox/MasterProject/kni/KNI_4.3.0/include/KNI_LM/lmBase.h:73: undefined reference to `CikBase::~CikBase()'
/home/aslund/Dropbox/MasterProject/kni/KNI_4.3.0/include/KNI_LM/lmBase.h:73: undefined reference to `CikBase::~CikBase()'
```

I have tried so many things, but what worked a few days ago seems to lead to nothing now. I have tried making everything from scratch, but with the same result. Another point to make is that I am running ROS Fuerte with the newest updates. Could it be these updates that causes the error or is there a totally different reason why linking the wrapper to my interface fails?

Regards

Sebastian Aslund

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31627/linking-problems-between-two-packages/) by [Aslund](https://answers.ros.org/users/163/aslund/) on ROS Answers with karma: 289 on 2012-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are many build changes in Fuerte, and problems like this crop up from time to time. That is why it is still in Beta test, not fully released.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0